# Is it possible to compile individual software from the FreeBSD source tree?

Tags: compiling, freebsd, debugging

I wonder if it is possible to compile individual software packages from FreeBSD source tree without compiling the whole kernel and world....Say,for example `ex` , which is included in the `nvi` (new vi) source code.

https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/contrib/nvi/

My intention is to compile, if possible, individual software with debug symbols enabled, so I will be able to debug the code/software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, with the standard `/usr/src` installed it might run something like

```
# cat /etc/src.conf
CFLAGS=-pipe
DEBUG_FLAGS=-g
# cd /usr/src/usr.bin/vi
# make clean && make obj && make depend && make && make install
# gdb -d /usr/src/contrib/nvi/ex -d /usr/src/contrib/nvi/common -tui ex
```

Comment: And, will this overwrite existing `nvi` (`vi`, `ex`, etc...) installation? Thanks